# Insert in DB array checkbox rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Need help for array insert in db using check box.

```
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'company_name[]', company.company_name %> <%= company.id %>
  <% end %>
```

how to insert this in create method

```
  def create
       @ebookAssignedCompanies = EbookCompanyAssigned.create(ebook_company_assigned_param)
       @ebookAssignedCompanies.save
  end

   private

  def ebook_company_assigned_param    
   params.permit(company_name:[]) 
  end
```

the result in mysql table is

```
 +-------------+------------+
 | id |  company_name       |
 +-------------+------------+
 |  1 | ["MHT, "PMT"]       |
 +-------------+------------+
```

ny desired result

```
  +-------------+------------+
  | id |  company_name       |
  +-------------+------------+
  |  1 | MHT                 |
  |  2 | PMT                 |
  +-------------+------------+
```

please need help for this thank you

Comment: You can do this using a loop over `params['company_name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create
  @ebookCompanyAssigneds = []
  @errors = []
  params['company_name'].each do |cName|
    eBookC = EbookCompanyAssigned.new(:company_name => cName)
    if eBookC.valid?
      @ebookCompanyAssigneds << eBookC.save
    else
      @errors += eBookC.errors
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @coolshox, It'll tell you the errors while creating the new companies. I guess it's better way to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
def create
  params["company_name"].each do |obj|
       @ebookAssignedCompanies = EbookCompanyAssigned.new(company_name: obj)
       @ebookAssignedCompanies.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @punnet18  it shows error 
undefined local variable or method `company_name'

Comment: @coolshox accept and vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
params.permit(company_name:[])
```

that's return a Hash

```
{company_name: <Array of passing values>}
```

that's why you create only one record with array of names inside company_name attribute.

If you instead need create as many records as elements into 'company_name' params passed you should write:

```
def create
  params.permit(company_name: [])[:company_name].each do |name|
    EbookCompanyAssigned.create(company_name: name)
  end
end
```

or:

```
def create
  array_of_hashes = params.permit(company_name: [])[:company_name]
    .inject([]) { |array, name| array << {company_name: name} }
  EbookCompanyAssigned.create(array_of_hashes)
end
```

Comment: @DjezzL thanks for the complete explanation. I will take note for this.